# SQL Server default values

Tags: c#, api, sql-server-2019

I have an app that uses a Web API to connect to a server. One of the columns, `IsActive`, is set to a default value of true or 1. The column defined as a `bit` datatype.

When I make an entry into the table using SQL Server, `IsActive` is set to 1. If I make the entry using Postman or the app, the value of `IsActive` is set to 0.

My questions are:

1. Are default values only for entries made using SQL Server?
2. If I want a default value placed into the table, in this scenario do I need to program the API to do this? Or can I rely on SQL Server to do it?

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework / EF Core? If so, it's a limitation of EF: EF always uses explicit values for `INSERT`, it never uses `DEFAULT`.

Comment: If you always explicitly set the value, you'll never have to worry about the default behavior. According to [bit (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/bit-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16): _An integer data type that can take a value of 1, 0, or NULL...Converting to bit promotes any nonzero value to 1._

Answer (score 2):

Looks like what @Dai commented answers your first question that it's likely a limitation of entity framework in your WebApi that is causing the issue.

To answer your second question.

If you have a model with the property `public bool IsActive`, that you want to default  to `true` then you will need to make sure you assign `IsActive = true` before saving the record. Otherwise your API is passing `false` by default to the database.

Comment: SQL's `bit` type only allows `NULL` when the column is defined as `IsActive bit NULL` (as opposed to `IsActive bit NOT NULL`) just like any other type.

Comment: Good point! I suspect the database has it `IsActive bit NULL` since it is saving the records. If it was `IsActive bit NOT NULL` then I would expect an error to be returned to the WebApi. Unless IsActive is somehow being defaulted to 0 rather than null in the API.

Comment: The OP never said anything about `NULL`s btw. They only said `IsActive` was saved as `0` in SQL Server, which corresponds to .NET's `false` bool value, which in-turn is the value of `default(Boolean)`, so the evidence suggests the OP simply never assigned `IsActive = true`.

Comment: Aw that makes sense. So by default `bool IsActive` is `false` not `null` in the model.